# Very slow inner join query

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to optimalize this query for being fast (takes around 10 minutes)

```
UPDATE year_2021 t1 
        INNER JOIN pricelist t2 
             ON t1.material = t2.material
SET t1.rabat = t2.rs
```

Table year_2021 have 30k rows and table pricelist have 60k rows.

Is it really ok, this query takes 10 minutes or it is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: If this is run a few times a year and does not cause any issues, then I would not spend a whole lot of time of optimising the query. If you still want to optimise it, then you need to share the explain for the query and the list of existing indexes on both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `pricelist` have `INDEX(material, rs)`

Comment: It will speed up for sure, but index on "pricelist.rs" will also slow down the update - maybe better to skip that

Comment: @domi27 - The speedup provided by my index will be orders of magnitude more than the slowdown due to some other index.  (And the index on rs _may_ be useful somewhere else; I have no insight into this.)

Comment: no doubt and was no criticism .. just a comment ;-)

Comment: Thank you! From 10 minutes it takes only 2 minutes! :)

Comment: Sorry that it was not "orders of magnitude" faster.  Perhaps lots of rows needed to be Updated.